# Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I a tiring to upload excel sheet and insert data in MySQL database.
when I debug I am getting below error:

Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Below my code:

```
enter code here
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new UploadUsingEntity.Domain.Concrete.ExcelStructureInitializer());

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

helper class

```
  public DataSet ReadExcelFile(string filePath, out string msg, string isHDR = "Yes")
    {
        string details = string.Empty;
        List<Excelstructure> lstEntityTable = repository.ExcelStructure.Where(
                     x => x.File_Name.Equals("EmployeeExcel", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).
            OrderBy(x => x.Row_No).ToList();
        List<string> lstFieldType = new List<string>();
        lstFieldType.AddRange(lstEntityTable[1].Field_Data.ToString().Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        DataTable dt = CreateDataTableFromList(lstEntityTable);
        DataSet ds = GetDataFromMultipleSheets(filePath, lstFieldType);
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        for (byte i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                details = ValidateExcelHeadings(dt, ds.Tables[i]);
                ds.DataSetName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            }
        }
        msg = details;
        return ds;
    }
```

ExcelStructure entites

```
[Table("ExcelStructure")]
  public class Excelstructure
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Row_ID { get; set; }

    public int File_ID { get; set; }

    public string File_Name { get; set; }

    public string Field_Name { get; set; }

    public string Field_Data { get; set; }

    public int Active_Flag { get; set; }

    public int Row_No { get; set; }

    public string Field_Delimeter { get; set; }
}
```

outstanding entites

```
 [Table("outstanding")]
public class oustanding
{
   [Key]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int ServiceProviderID { get; set; }
    public string TotalDue { get; set; }
    public string LastPaidAmount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastPaidDate { get; set; }
    public string OutStandingDescription { get; set; }
    public string longitudeandlatitude { get; set; }
}





 public class ExcelStructureInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
    {
        //base.Seed(context);
        var excelStructure = new List<Excelstructure>()
        {
            new Excelstructure(){ File_ID=1, Field_Name="outstanding", Field_Data="CustomerID|Name|PhoneNumber|Address|ServiceProviderID|TotalDue|LastPaidAmount|LastPaidDate|OutStandingDescription|longitudeandlatitude", Active_Flag=1, Row_No=1, File_Name="oustanding", Field_Delimeter="|"},
            new Excelstructure(){ File_ID=1, Field_Name="DataType", Field_Data="S|S|I|S|I|S|S|D|S|S", Active_Flag=1, Row_No=2, File_Name="outstanding", Field_Delimeter="|"},
            new Excelstructure(){ File_ID=1, Field_Name="Size", Field_Data="50|100|20|100|10|100|100|20|100|100", Active_Flag=1, Row_No=3, File_Name="outstanding", Field_Delimeter="|"},
            new Excelstructure(){ File_ID=1, Field_Name="Mandatory", Field_Data="Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|N|N|N|N|N", Active_Flag=1, Row_No=4, File_Name="outstanding", Field_Delimeter="|"},
            new Excelstructure(){ File_ID=1, Field_Name="Param", Field_Data="@CustomerID|@Name|@PhoneNumber|@Address|@ServiceProviderID|@TotalDue|@LastPaidAmount|@LastPaidDate|@OutStandingDescription|@longitudeandlatitude", Active_Flag=1, Row_No=5, File_Name="outstanding", Field_Delimeter="|"},
        };
        context.ExcelStructure.AddRange(excelStructure);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

}

Comment: I am following below tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/uploading-multiple-records-via-excel-upload-in-database-usin/

Comment: Nothing is wrong in my code? did any one find where I did mistake please help me

Answer (score 1):

What this error implicates is that the database was not created by Entity Framework so it cannot make sure whether your model can be used with this database. The reason is most likely that you've created the database with the script in the article:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExcelStructure] ....
```

However the ExcelStructureInitializer will take care of the creation of your database so delete the database and leave it to the initializer to create the structure and the seed data.

By the way if you want to support production code you should consider Migrations instead of a Database Initializer.